# How to search a record based on id's in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

My record looks like below,

```
"recordIds" : [
    ObjectId("58738da9796c616bdec43404"),
    ObjectId("58736ffbff7a0c2391c184fd")
]
```

I want to get the students belonged to this id and for that i wrote a query as bellow,

```
recordIds.forEach(function(i,v){
    Student.find({ _id: v }, function (err, students) {
        if (!err) {
            json.students = students;
        }
    });
});
```

My Model:

```
students: [{
    type : Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Student'
}],
```

Comment: try to use db.students.find({_id: {$in: recordIds}})

Answer (score 1):

This will get exactly what you want, but easier.

```
db.students.find({ _id: { $in: recordIds } })
```

Comment: Hi Tolga,do i need any for loop because i have 2 records.

Comment: No you don't, the whole idea behing `$in` keyword is only this funtionality.